# Callback returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, gmail-api

I'm trying to get data from the GMail API to be able to load attachment data from there base64 encryption though when I try to return it I am getting undefined.

```
$Message['Content']['Attachment'][$Count]['Data'] = getAttachments($Message['Details']['ID'], message['payload']['parts'][key], function (filename, mimeType, attachment) {
    return 'data:'+mimeType+';base64,'+attachment.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
});


function getAttachments(messageID, parts, callback) {
     var attachId = parts.body.attachmentId;
     var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
          'id': attachId,
          'messageId': messageID,
          'userId': 'me'
     });
     request.execute(function (attachment) {
           callback(parts.filename, parts.mimeType, attachment);
     });
}
```

The problem seems to be that the data is being made available after the function has returned a value.  This has been tested through console.log().

Answer (score 1):

It is not the callback returning undefined - it is `getAttachments()`.

The call to the GMail API is asynchronous, so you cannot assign to `$Message...['Data']` in this way - you are actually assigning the result of `getAttachments()` which doesn't return anything, hence the `undefined`.

You won't have the data available until you are in the actual callback, so you need to be setting the value in the callback itself:

```
getAttachments($Message['Details']['ID'], message['payload']['parts'][key], function (filename, mimeType, attachment) {
    var data = 'data:'+mimeType+';base64,'+attachment.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');

    // now you have the data, you can set the property
    $Message['Content']['Attachment'][$Count]['Data'] = data;
});
```

You will probably have to move other processing of your `$Message` into here too, e.g. sending it.

Answer (score 0):

`getAttachments()` function didn't return any value, that's why it's `undefined`.

### Solution:

```
getAttachments($Message['Details']['ID'], message['payload']['parts'][key],function (filename, mimeType, attachment) 
{
    $Message['Content']['Attachment'][$Count]['Data'] =  'data:'+mimeType+';base64,'+attachment.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
});
```